# Access denied creating App_Data subdirectory

Tags: security, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership, app-data

I've created a user from the ASP.NET Configuration 
I'm using sql server but I haven't created any database for membership.

I did add this to the config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="admin" />
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

where admin is the user I did creat.
and it works very well localy.

after I have uploded my website I got an error that I have to create an App_Data folder with write permission and add it to my application folder, now I get this :

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error message that you are getting will only occur on a remote call. It may work locally fine. This is due to the fact that the remote connections are not enabled on the SQL Server surface Area configuration. To accomplish this, please follow below steps:

Make sure your database engine is configured to accept remote connections:
 • ***Start > All Programs > SQL Server 2005 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Surface Area Configuration
 • Click on Surface Area Configuration for Services and Connections
 • Select the instance that is having a problem > Database Engine > Remote Connections
 • Enable local and remote connections
 • Restart instance***

Alternatively, if you are using a named SQL Server instance, make sure you are using that instance name in your connection strings in your ASweb P.NET application
 • Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename
 • Check your connection string as well

**

**

Comment: hi Prashant, thnx for ur answer, I'm using 2008 and here wt I've done: SQL Server 2008 > right-click on the instance name > Facets > Select "Surface Area Configuration" from the Facet drop down > I didn't find something like wt u have said so I checked RemoteDacEnabled (true) [http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1673] but nothig happened :$

Comment: Do you have Sql Server Management Studio. If yes, then you can open it and right click the instance in question, go to Properties -> Connections -> Check "Allow remote connections to this server".

You might also have to enable TCP/IP Protocol to be enabled thru Configuration Manager.